# Is it possible to revert the action in Firebase Cloud Storage?

Tags: firebase-storage, google-cloud-console

Folders with images in my entire bucket are almost all gone. I do have a backup, but I don't know if it's possible to upload multiple folders with files at once.
Is there any possibility to revert the accidental deletion of folders in bucket in Cloud Console or are there any snapshots of storages being kept?